# What is the way to incremental sftp from remote server to azure using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

What is the way to incremental sftp from remote server to azure using azure data factory. I have a scenario where i need to copy files from remote server to azure.

Comment: Do you mean moves files from an SFTP server to, say Blob Storage as they appear in SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

to do this kind of copy task in Azure Data Factory, create a pipeline with a Copy activity in it, set the source dataset as [SFTP dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp) and the sink dataset as [Azure blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage). You could also consider to use [Copy data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool) in Azure data factory.